# Unable to access google map in Android program

Tags: android, google-maps

In this code i have some problem, here I am unable to access google map, Square boxes occur in place of map. Can anyone help me to short out this problem.

GPSApp.java class

package com.android.gpsapp;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

 public class GPSApp extends MapActivity
 {
  MapView mapView; 
  MapController mc;
  GeoPoint p;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, MapView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 

    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

    mc = mapView.getController();

    String coordinates[] = {"26.456435","80.330606"};
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

    p = new GeoPoint(
        (int) (lat * 1E6), 
        (int) (lng * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(17); 
    mapView.invalidate();

    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    mapView.setTraffic(true);
}

  @Override
   protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return false;
    }
 }
```

Main.xml and API_key i have already given

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zoom" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    /> 

   <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
   android:id="@+id/mapView" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   android:enabled="true"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:apiKey="API_Key"
   /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifes.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.android.gpsapp"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity android:name="GPSApp" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
   </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you running on emulator or device ?

Answer (score 0):

Try extending FragmentActivity

```
public class Maps extends FragmentActivity {
    GoogleMap map;
    double lat;
    double lan;
    boolean flag = false;

    // private LocationManager lm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapptry);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
             }
        }
```

Comment: i am trying to extend FragmentActivity but it gives error can you explain this.

Comment: Import this **import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;**

Comment: also go to your project->properties->java Build path ->libraries -> add external jars and add then go to **\android-sdks\extras\android\support\v4** and select **android-support-v4.jar**.. this should get rid of your error

Comment: I am using netbeans and it is unable to select this jar. once i select this jar and then if i again go to properties it doesn't selected jar.

Comment: Well i haven't worked with net Beans.. so i dont think i can answer your question.Sorry . But ideally that's how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving `<uses-permission>` to be before `<application>`, as Android used to be fussy about that sort of thing.

If that does not help, try running the Maps application on the emulator or device. If it exhibits the same problems, then the issue is with your ability to download map information from Google.

If the Maps application works, and yours does not, then your API key is incorrect, such as trying to use a Maps V2 API key on a Maps V1 app. Your code is set up for Maps V1, and you can no longer get Maps V1 API keys.  You should consider switching to use Maps V2, as Maps V1 is officially deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I can think of here is that you are trying to implement `Google Maps API V1`, while the current Google Maps API version is 2. So either you are trying to use Google Maps API V2 key with Google Maps API V1 in this case the problem you describe will occur (No map, only squares‏ with zoom controls)

If you did produces an API V1 key (which I'm realy doubt of...) then the problem is probably somewhere with the way you defined you application in the Google API Console.

In any way I would suggest to you to move to Google API v2 as API V1 is deprecated.

Here is a blog post I wrote on how to implement Google Maps API V2 in your application:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)